# C3# Asp.net Paypal IPN

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I have `Button1` as a pay button and is sending a payment to my business account for paypal. Ive followed this [guide](http://pankajsharma163.blogspot.com/2011/11/paypal-integration-in-aspnet.html) and the payment sends perfectly and even shows in my ipn history. I have my IPN notification URL set to "domain/pay_ipn.aspx". 
The problem fails verrification and always apears invalid in the `pay_ipn.aspx` page

WebConfig to store paypal urls

```
<appSettings>
<add key="token" value="PW1BDVNqVPVanwduF_Tb2Ey91aT1Uhx1kL7HPc-7e8S-6AnUwSSHyasolSe" />
<add key="paypalemail" value="email@yahoo.com" />
<!--Here i used sandbox site url only if you hosted in live change sandbox to live paypal URL-->
<add key="PayPalSubmitUrl" value="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" />
<add key="FailedURL" value="domain/dashboard.aspx" />
<add key="SuccessURL" value="domain/dashboard.aspx" />
<add key="NotifyURL" value="domain/pay_ipn.aspx" />
```

payemnt page

```
 private void PayWithPayPal(string amount, string itemInfo, string name, string currency)
        {
            string redirecturl = "";

            //Mention URL to redirect content to paypal site
            redirecturl += "http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" +
                           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalemail"].ToString();

            //First name i assign static based on login details assign this value
            redirecturl += "&first_name=" + name;

            //Product Name
            redirecturl += "&item_name=" + itemInfo;

            //Product Name
            redirecturl += "&amount=" + amount;


            //Shipping charges if any
            redirecturl += "&shipping=0";

            //Handling charges if any
            redirecturl += "&handling=0";

            //Currency code 
            redirecturl += "&currency=" + currency;

            //Success return page url
            redirecturl += "&return=" +
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString();
            //notify return page url
            redirecturl += "&notify_url=" +
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotifyURL"].ToString();
            //Failed return page url
            redirecturl += "&cancel_return=" +
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString();

            Response.Redirect(redirecturl);
        }
```

pay_ipn.aspx

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //Post back to either sandbox or live
      string strSandbox = "http://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
      string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
      HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strLive);
      //Set values for the request back
      req.Method = "POST";
      req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
      string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
      string strResponse_copy = strRequest;  //Save a copy of the initial info sent by PayPal
      strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
      req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

      //for proxy
      //WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#"));
      //req.Proxy = proxy;
      //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
      StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
      streamOut.Write(strRequest);
      streamOut.Close();
      StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
      string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
      streamIn.Close();

      if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
      {
          //check the payment_status is Completed
          //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
          //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
          //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
          //process payment

          // pull the values passed on the initial message from PayPal

          NameValueCollection these_argies = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strResponse_copy);
          string user_email = these_argies["payer_email"];
          string pay_stat = these_argies["payment_status"];
          string fName = these_argies["first_name"];
          string itemName = these_argies["item_name"];
          //.
          //.  more args as needed look at the list from paypal IPN doc
          //.
          TextBox1.Text += "Verified: "+pay_stat + Environment.NewLine;

          if (pay_stat.Equals("Completed"))
          {
              TextBox1.Text += "complete";

          }


          // more checks needed here specially your account number and related stuff
      }
      else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
      {
          TextBox1.Text = "INVALID";
          //log for manual investigation
      }
      else
      {
          TextBox1.Text = "error";
          //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
      }
  }
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: You must be close to getting it working since you are getting the string "INVALID".I suspect there is something wrong with the headers in the http messages.Usually I recommend two things to start troubleshooting these issues.First see if your account setting are correct by using an IE to go to site.Second use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture the http messages.  If the IE works,you can compare IE header results and application results using the sniffer.Get the status of the responses.  Should Be 200 DONE if successful.Also delete cookies from IE.  I bad cookie could give errors.

Comment: @JCM how can i track the payment! Its obviously sending thru but not showing it on the pay_ipn

Comment: @jdweng ok ill see what shows up. I can tell you that the IPN details that are shown in the history shows the 200 http response code. Am i sending params worng on the pay_ipn??

Comment: Can't tell.  The parameters should be in the http headers of sniffer results.

Comment: @jdweng this is what is being sent to post to in the pay_ipn. Is there other parameters to post? 

&cmd=_notify-validate

Comment: Where did you get this code from.  Looks like c++ not c# : strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";  This looks like a callback event where cmd is the callback method ( address of where method is located).

Comment: @jdweng http://pankajsharma163.blogspot.com/2011/11/paypal-integration-in-aspnet.html

Comment: @jdweng my problem is that the ipn is not filling in the params to check! its only posting "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr&cmd=_notify-validate" How do i receive the params after payment.. 
ex) 
.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr&cmd=_notifyvalidate&item_name=ITEM

Comment: @jdweng i got it working! Ty